# How to insert array of values in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can I insert values inside an array to a database into their own rows?

here is the array:

```
  $nombre_bene = $_POST['nombre-bene'];
  $cedula_bene = $_POST['ci-bene'];
  $nacimiento_bene = $_POST['nacimiento-bene'];
  $parentezco_bene = $_POST['parentezco-bene'];
  $servicios_bene = $_POST['servicios-bene0'];
  $id_titular =  $_POST['plan-tipo'];

  $data_beneficiario = array(
    'nombre' => $nombre_bene,
    'cedula' => $cedula_bene,
    'nacimiento' => $nacimiento_bene,
    'parentezco' => $parentezco_bene,
    'id' => $id_titular,
    'servicios' => $servicios_bene
  );
```

The thing is each $_POST is coming as an array (because I need it that way)

I tried to go with a foreach in the $data_beneficiario array.. but the thing is that each variable is an indexed array.. I'm inyecting the values wit ha prepared PHP function

```
  $statement2 = $connection->prepare(" INSERT INTO beneficiarios (nombre_bene, cedula_bene, fechan_bene, parentezco, id_titular_bene, servicios_adicionales) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
      $statement2->bind_param("ssssis", $nombre_bene, $cedula_bene, $nacimiento_bene, $parentezco_bene, $id_titular, $servicios_bene);
```

but I don't in which way to insert the values in a way each value goes into their own column. I will appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

First combine the individual field arrays into rows.

```
$rows = array_map(
    null,
    $_POST['nombre-bene'],
    $_POST['ci-bene'],
    $_POST['nacimiento-bene'],
    $_POST['parentezco-bene'],
    $_POST['servicios-bene0'],
    $_POST['plan-tipo']
);
```

Next, insert each row:

```
for ($rows as $row) {
    $statement = $connection->prepare('insert into beneficiarios (nombre_bene, cedula_bene, fechan_bene, parentezco, id_titular_bene, servicios_adicionales) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
    $statement->bind_param("ssssis", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5]);
    $statement->execute() or die $connection->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming each of the arrays has the same number of entries, you could just do this. Note I use `array_values` to guarantee all the arrays have the same indices:

```
$nombre_bene = array_values($_POST['nombre-bene']);
$cedula_bene = array_values($_POST['ci-bene']);
$nacimiento_bene = array_values($_POST['nacimiento-bene']);
$parentezco_bene = array_values($_POST['parentezco-bene']);
$servicios_bene = array_values($_POST['servicios-bene0']);
$id_titular =  array_values($_POST['plan-tipo']);

$statement2 = $connection->prepare(" INSERT INTO beneficiarios (nombre_bene, cedula_bene, fechan_bene, parentezco, id_titular_bene, servicios_adicionales) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
foreach (array_keys($nombre_bene) as $k) {
    $statement2->bind_param("ssssis", $nombre_bene[$k], $cedula_bene[$k], $nacimiento_bene[$k], $parentezco_bene[$k], $id_titular[$k], $servicios_bene[$k]);
    $statement2->execute();
}
```